# Angle of reflection on 3d Object

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am rasterizing some 3d objects (x,y,z) onto a 2d plane (x,y) and I want to color the rasterized cells based on the angle of reflection of an angle of incidence that comes from directly above the centroid (as seen in diagram).

How do I calculate the angle of reflection on the X,Y plane given a 3d line of incidence and a 3d polygon?

[[image: rasterization of angle of reflection1]

Comment: Typical computer rendering is done using a normal vector at the point of reflection.  So in your case, figure out which face it is, and use the normal to that face.  Angle of incidence = angle of reflection, they are on opposite sides of the normal.

Comment: OK, looks like I can use the cross-product of two of the vertices to get the normal. How do I compute the 2d angle on the x,y axis with that normal?

Comment: You normally don't use the angle itself, but the *cosine* of the angle, via $$\cos\theta = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{\left\lVert\vec{a}\right\rVert \left\lVert\vec{b}\right\rVert}$$where $\cdot$ denotes vector dot product, and $\lVert\vec{p}\rVert = \sqrt{\vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}}$ denotes the Euclidean length of vector $\vec{p}$.  ($\theta$ being the angle between 2D or 3D vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.)